# 2x2 MIMO communications, SNR, and data throughput vs link robustness trade off

Tags: wireless

With information about data throughput in a 2x2 MIMO environment and without knowing the channel state information is there a way  one can reliably estimate the receive SNR based on the throughput in a Wi-Fi OFDM link?

Answer (score 0):

No. That's mathematically impossible (you'd need to know the magnitude of the singular values of a matrix you explicitly say you don't have), and even if you would know these singular values, you would need knowledge about the actual data demands (which never are uniform), receiver and transmitter characteristics, the interference situation (unlicensed band, collision-detection based multiple access scheme).